# Get created controls in ContentPresenter before binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate

Is it possible to get the controls inside of a `ContentPresenter` after the content is created using a `DataTemplate` and before the `DataBinding` was executed? This is needed because some controls needs to be `Initialized` using a method before binding was executed. The controls are defines in a `ResourceDictionary/DataTemplate`. Thanks a lot!

So my idea was to get all controls which needs to be initialized using a `Visual TreeHelper`.

Call order:

1. Set UI DataContext
2. ContentPresenter set DataTemplate
3. ContentPresenter creates its content
4. << Initialize methods>>
5. Execute binding
6. Be happy.

Comment: Did you try to add a Loaded event handler to those controls?

Comment: The `Loaded` event does not help. Because I have no code behind. The Templates are in a separate xaml file which is loaded using a Template selector.